# What is the average number of glowstone per chunk?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glowstone#Natural_generation) it only states that "...it generates in crystalline clusters on the underside of ceilings or overhangs." No numbers are to be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the 1.16 nether update, some areas of ceiling in the nether are no longer netherrack (soul sand valley and basalt delta), and glowstone blobs only spawn on those. After doing some quick experimenting, there are would be around 1.8 glowstone blocks, each 5.5 away if all the glowstone was spread evenly (this is not actually how it is unfortunately). For actual spawning sizes and frequencies, there are about 29 glowstone blocks every 88 blocks. Please note that this does not account for the areas where it cannot spawn. For every chunk, there will be just about five blocks.

Comment: Sorry if the answer is worded poorly, I wrote it in a hurry.

Comment: Note: during the time while I was recording information, there were a few outliers: they were small blobs that were about 10 blocks apart and about 15 blocks each in size. In these clusters, there would be 2 to 3 blobs. I counted these as outliers and left them out.